# Converting anonymous type to List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion, key-value

I have a method requiring the following:

```
public static List<ParetoElement> 
     ParetoBuildBySum(List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> inputData)
```

I have the following linq query and would like those two anonymous values in a list of KeyValuePairs (string and double) to pass in.

```
var myHistoSource = from d in data 
                    select new 
                    { 
                       Type = d.Item_Expense_Type, 
                       Amount = Double.Parse(d.Item_Amount.ToString()) 
                    };
```

What's the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify your query accordingly:

```
var myHistoSource = (
    from d in data 
    select new KeyValuePair<string, double>(d.Item_Expense_Type,
                                            Double.Parse(d.Item_Amount.ToString())
    ).ToList();
```

As an aside, your `ParetoBuildBySum` method should most likely accept an `IEnumerable` instead of a `List` as its parameter.